# Getting a gap between border and banner in gmail html template(All other email looks good)

Tags: html, templates, gmail

Output in Gmail:

[image: Output in Gmail]

Am getting the output as shown in the image is from gmail. All other email outputs are looks good. Kindly me on this to resolve this gap between banner and boder in Gmail.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try using `width:100vw;` on the banner tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]